# Django Admin list_filter by reverse lookups

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-filter

I have 2 models involved.
one related to the other by foreign keys.

in BarAdmin I wish to create a list filter by Foo entities related to the bar entity.

something similar to list_filter = (('user', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter), ) but reverse

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(Bar, related_name='a')

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I'm using django 1.8.4 and python 3.5.2

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you give a specific query condition for which you want a filter?

Comment: updated the post :)